# tell me how to use <Google Maps SDK>

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) cannot connect or validate `APIKey: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x167a06f0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=h ttps://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=h ttps://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x16522e20 "The request timed out."}`

like this,I thy many times it also log  [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE3t6.png) message ,but my BID is the same as the BID in google Developers Console ,could you tell me how can I do to show the map?

Answer (score 2):

Jass, I'm not mobile developer but something tells me that your url have empty space `h ttps://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap`. It should be `https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap`